# Import "prompts" in quickly (Simple Player tutorial)

Tags: python, application-development, quickly

I am following [this tutorial](https://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/multimedia/creating-a-simple-media-player/) on quickly. At one point I have to write `from quickly import prompts` in the file called `SimplePlayerWindow.py`. But when I do that and run my application, I get the following error:

```
from quickly import prompts
ImportError: cannot import name prompts
```

In the Python console IDLE, I tried to launch the command `help("quickly")` and this is the output:

```
Help on package quickly:

NAME
    quickly

FILE
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickly/__init__.py

MODULE DOCS
    http://docs.python.org/library/quickly

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    api
    builtincommands
    bzrbinding
    commands
    configurationhandler
    coreupgrade
    launchpadaccess
    quicklyconfig
    templatetools
    tools
    version
```

So there is no "prompts" listed.
What should I do? Are my programs updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the package [python-quickly.widgets](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-quickly.widgets/) but be careful since it is experimental and there are bugs.

Then run `from quickly import prompts` like you did before in a Python script.

Comment: So do you believe that the tutorial is outdated ?

Comment: What import command should I do then ?

Comment: If the issue was that the Quickly widgets package needed to be installed, that is clearly outlined in the Requirements section at the beginning of the tutorial.